# SQL for identifying % of orders placed within 20 minutes of each other

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, resultset, self-join

Have a dataset like below and would like to know various ways to solve the question of : what % of orders were within 20 minutes of each other?

| CustomerId | Order_# | Order_Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 000112 | 12/25/2011 10:30 |
| 123 | 000113 | 12/25/2011 10:35 |
| 123 | 000114 | 12/25/2011 10:45 |
| 123 | 000115 | 12/25/2011 10:55 |
| 456 | 000113 | 12/25/2011 10:35 |
| 456 | 000113 | 1/25/2011 10:30 |
| 789 | 000117 | 9/25/2011 2:00 |

Result set should look like this:

3/7 = 0.42%

My approach was to first do a Self join with the table to get a count of rows which fall within the 20% but struggling to take out the duplicate rows.

Anyways, look forward to seeing some crafty answers.

Thank you.

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.  Also tag with the database you are using.

Comment: Thank you Gordon, added tag for SQL Server

Comment: I count 4 that are within 20 minutes of another order, not 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lead()` and `lag()`:

```
select avg( case when prev_order_date > order_date - interval '20 minute' or
                      next_order_date < order_date + interval '20 minute'
                 then 1.0 else 0
            end) as ratio_within_20_minutes
from (select t.*,
             lag(order_date) over (partition by customer_id order by order_date) as prev_order_date,
             lead(order_date) over (partition by customer_id order by order_date) as next_order_date
      from t
     ) t;
```

Note that date/time functions vary a lot among databases.  This uses Standard SQL syntax for the comparisons.  The exact syntax probably varies, depending on your database.

If you want this *per customer* then add `group by customer_id` to the query and `customer_id` to the `select`.

EDIT:

In SQL Server, this would be:

```
select avg( case when prev_order_date > dateadd(minute, -20, order_date) or
                      next_order_date < dateadd(minute, 20, order_date)
                 then 1.0 else 0
            end) as ratio_within_20_minutes
from (select t.*,
             lag(order_date) over (partition by customer_id order by order_date) as prev_order_date,
             lead(order_date) over (partition by customer_id order by order_date) as next_order_date
      from t
     ) t;
```

Comment: Thank you. Would the below modified query also give the same result?                   
               SELECT  SUM(TIMEDIFF)/CONVERT(decimal(4,2),COUNT(ORDER_ID))

  FROM
  (
  SELECT  CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE,prev_order_date,next_order_date) <20 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS TIMEDIFF,
  T.*
  FROM ( select t.*,
             lag(DatetimN) over (partition by customer_id order by DatetimN) as prev_order_date,
             lead(DatetimN) over (partition by customer_id order by DatetimN) as next_order_date
      from [dbo].[SAMPLE_ORDER2] t) t
   )A